# A formula for heads and tail sequences

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking for a formula $f(m,n)$ where m and n are positive integers such that $m \leq n$, such that $f(m,n)$ is the number of n-length sequences of heads and tails where there is at least one run of length at least m. An m-run is a sequence of m consecutive heads or tails. For example, there are 16 5-length sequences with runs of length at least 3. So, $f(3,5)=16$. I am trying to find a nice formula for that function. Has any mathematician worked on anything like this before? If so, I would like to read it.

Comment: I get $f(3,5) = 8$, am I missing something?

Comment: @naslundx You are only counting the runs of heads.

Comment: Oh, I see, so at least one run m-run of heads or one m-run of tails, or both?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now, I would like a nice formula for this function.

Comment: At least for $m > \frac{n}{2}$, I believe we can use $f(m,n) = 2(2^{m-n} + (m - n)2^{n-m-1})$. When $m \leq \frac{n}{2}$ however we can have both a run of heads and of tails in the same and need to work out how not to count them several times.

Comment: Is there even a closed form expression at all.

Answer (score 1):

Odlyzko ["Enumeration of Strings"](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/string.enumerate.pdf) (in "Combinatorial Algorithms on Words" (Springer, 1985), pp. 205-228) gets the generating function for the number of  strings on $\{0, 1\}$ that don't contain a stretch of $k$ zeros as:
$$
B_{0^k}(z) = \frac{1 - z^k}{1 - 2 z + z^{k + 1}}
$$
Unless $k = 2$ (when this gives a Fibonacci number), no simple functions are forthcomming.

I don't see a simple way to extend the techniques used to consider simultaneously excluding stretches of zeros and ones.

Comment: I might add that it's easy to obtain this generating function (or any other generating function for sequences that avoid a given collection of words) with the so-called Goulden-Jackson Cluster method. See http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/gj.html .