# Count Binary Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

A binary number(which contains only 0’s and 1’s) is K-binary if it does not contain K consecutive zeros and does not have leading zeros.

I want to Find the number of K-Binary Numbers of length N.

Example : If N=1 and K=1 then answer is 1

If N=3 and K=2 then answer is 3.

What will be formula in terms of N and K?

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah it will work.

Comment: How did you come across this problem? It looks like it might be a contest or challenge problem of some sort.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah it was asked in a contest.I dont remember name of contest though.

Comment: I'm not too keen on giving complete answers to a contest that might still be ongoing, so I'll limit myself to a **hint**: Let $f(n)$ be the number of bit strings of length $n$ that both start and end with `1` and don't contain $k$ consecutive zeroes. You're then looking for $f(n-1)$. You can write down a recurrence for $f$ and solve that by any standard technique.

Comment: It's easy enough to account for the strings with leading zeros. As to strings containing consecutive zeros, here's a recent, equivalent question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715356/a-formula-for-heads-and-tail-sequences

Answer (score 0):

A generating function (for fixed K and for the complement) is shown in http://oeis.org/A109435 . Associated references are in http://oeis.org/A050227 .