# Number of possible bit sequences of length m with at least n consecutive 1's in them

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

I have seen similar questions to this but they each seem to be special cases of this general question. Answering this would be beneficial to my research, but I am not a combinatorics expert, and this seemingly simple question eludes me. Is there a simple formula to calculate this? Everything I have seen online has been centered around things like "either 2 consecutive 1's or 0's" or "contains no ..".

If it helps, I know that for $m = 8$ bits and say the sequence is denoted $S(m,n)$
$$  
S(m = 8, n = 1) = 255 \\  
S(8,2) = 201  \\
S(8,3) = 107  \\
S(8,4) = 48   \\
S(8,5) = 20   \\
S(8,6) = 8   \\
S(8,7) = 3   \\
S(8,8) = 1 
$$

Interestingly I'm finding that $S(8,4)=S(9,5)=S(10,6)=S(11,7)=48$
I haven't tested $S(12,8)$ because I don't want my computer to melt but I'm seeing a pattern... However this does not seem to work for $m<8$.

Comment: Is the original $m$-bit string arbitrary? In other words, do we need to sum the number of all possible subsequences of all possible strings of length $m$?

Comment: Yes is there a closed-form solution to this type of thing?

Comment: Take for example the string $011100111$ and $m=3$, is $0111$ to be counted twice or once?

Comment: Just once. so 011100000,   000000111 and 011100111 would be considered distinct from one another.

Comment: Really what I want to know is how many hexadecimal numbers (8 bits) contain runs of 4 bits (no wrapping around) I know the answer is 48 (for 1 byte) but I wanted to generalize.

Comment: Then I think the question should be something like "Count the number of possible bit sequences of length $m$ with at least $n$ consecutive 1s in them".

Comment: Your right, I'll see if I can change the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ross Millikan formula, which I searched with [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz), I could find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/715773/573047), and using again Approach Zero with that result, this other [beautiful answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3106332/573047). Both give the complementary result, so in your case we have:

$$S(m,n) = 2^m-\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor m/n\rfloor}
{m-nq\choose q} (-1)^q 2^{m-(n+1)q}
+ \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor m/n\rfloor - 1}
{m-n(q+1)\choose q} (-1)^q 2^{m-n-(n+1)q}$$

See the links for details.

Comment: Still working through this gimme a minute to verify

Comment: Awesome works as expected. Thank you! Not sure why I was unable to get Ross's answer to work.

Comment: even works below $m=8$, but probably should reiterate the caveat that $n>=m/2$ is required

Comment: I think it does not have the restriction $n \ge m/2$.

Comment: I'll follow up in the morning but I recall testing one of the cases where n<m/2 that did not work. Think it was around m=6 and n = 2 or something.

Comment: Ok I was wrong, it does not have the restriction $n>=m/2$. Awesome answer, thanks for the links. Really appreciate everything.

Answer (score 2):

If the string is $m$ bits long and you demand a run of exactly $n\ 1$s we can find a formula for $n \ge \frac m2$.  Let us call this $T(m,n)$.  If the run is at one end of the string ($2$ choices) you need a $0$ at the end of the run and have $2^{m-n-1}$ choices for the other bits.  If the run is not at the end of the string, there are $m-n-1$ places it can start and you have $2^{m-n-2}$ choices to complete the string.  If $m-n-2$ is negative there are no other bits to fill in. So
$$T(m,n)=\begin {cases} 1&n=m\\2&n+1=m\\2^{m-n}+(m-n-1)2^{m-n-2}&n+2 \le m \end {cases} $$
and the fact that it only depends on $m-n$ is clear.  Then
$$S(m,n)=\sum_{i=n}^mT(m,i)$$
I repeat that this only works for $n \ge \frac m2$.  The reason it only depends on $m-n$ is because if you take a string of the type $(m,n)$ you can find a unique string of type $(m+1,n+1)$ by extending the run by one more bit.

Comment: $T(m,n) \rightarrow T(m,i)$.

Comment: I'm testing this but I'm not getting the correct results. Maybe you can show me where I go wrong. Try $S(8,4)$, we have for $n<=m-2$ the following results ($4<=i<=6$), -> ${24, 10, 4}$. Then for $i=m-1$ we have $2$, and then $1$ for $i=m$. This leaves a sum of ${24, 10, 4, 2, 1}$ which is $41$. Not $48$.

Comment: I found an off by $1$ error.  Now it gives $28,12,5,2,1$ for a total of $48$

Comment: @BillyJoe:  Correct.  Thanks.  Somehow I missed your comment earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I will not give a formula, but just a recurrence relation. Let T(m, n) be the number of strings of length m with a run of n consecutive 1's.

Consider all the strings of length m-1. Exactly T(m-1, n) of them already contain a string of 'n' consecutive digits. Since we can add a 0 or a 1 we will get double this amount of length m strings strings.

However adding a 1 in the m'th place will give a new good string if the last (n-1) digits are a 1 and the n'th to last digit is a 0 and in addition the digits in place 1, ..., m - n - 1 do not contain a run of n consecutive 1's. i.e. the string looks like this:
$$
\underbrace{xx..xx}_{m - n - 1}0\underbrace{11..11}_{n - 1}
$$
There are 2^{m - n - 1} possibilities for the x-digits, but we should exclude T(m - n - 1, n) of them to avoid the double counting.

Adding it all up we find
$$
T(m, n) = 2\cdot T(m - 1, n) - T(m - n - 1, n) + 2^{(m - n - 1)} 
$$

If $m - n - 1 \leq n$, i.e. $m \leq 2n + 1$, the $T(m - n - 1, n)$ term vanishes and you should be able to solve the recurrence relation.